# How do I point django settings.py to point mongoDB?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

Currently my `settings.py` looks something like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',   
        'NAME': 'gb',                      
        'USER': '',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      
        'PORT': '27017'                      
    }
}
```

and I am using django version is 1.4. The problem is when I try `python manage.py syncdb` it throws the following error

```
 db = dbs[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
 KeyError: 'default'
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Does `python manage.py syncdb --database=default` help?

Comment: The problem persists with even after using --database=default.

Comment: python manage.py syncdb  --settings=settings.dev

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to use a fork of Django and not vanilla django.  Unfortunately the site is down right now for me but the documentation and tutorial for django non-rel mongodb_engine is here: http://www.django-mongodb.org/ or you can contact via the usergroup see the project page on github https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine

Comment: It looks like the doc is now here: https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/